# Sync Microsoft Onedrive from a guest (Windows 10) to a folder in host (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am running a Windows 10 guest using VirtualBox that is installed on Ubuntu 18 and would like to sync the Microsoft Onedrive from Windows into a folder in Ubuntu. I have tried `OneDrive` package and that package is good for syncing my personal OneDrive, though I am trying to sync my OneDrive for business account in Ubuntu. I am also aware of sharing folders between host and guest, but Microsoft does not allow putting my OneDrive in the shared folder and if I create a shortcut, it is not accessible from the host.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Does [How to setup OneDrive in Ubuntu 17.04?](//askubuntu.com/q/958406) help at all?

Comment: This works for my personal OneDrive. The account that I am trying to share is OneDrive Bussiness. Thanks

Comment: You should add clarifications to the question itself, along with what you have tried and why that did not work. The way the question is currently written, it is not clear that you are aware of the `onedrive` package at all.

Comment: I edited the question. I am looking for a generic procedure that can be used for accessing any other folder like google drive from host. Sharing folder between host and guest is fairly simple, but accessing a cloud-based folder like MS OneDrive from the host is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update of what I have done to solve this problem. I have written as detailed as possible and hope it helps to solve other folks problem. Thanks to one of my dear friends who helped me with this.

> 1. Create the mount directory in the host machine (here we name it onedrive)
>      mkdir ~/onedrive
> 2. create credentials file
>      nano ~/.smbcreds
>      Add the following lines
>
>    ---
>
> > username= your username
> >
> > password= your password
> >
> > ---

chmod 600 ~/.smbcreds

> 3. On windows (Guest)
>      get properties on the folder you want to share >> go to sharing
>      change the share name to: Onedrive (assuming the name of both folders are same in host and guest)
>      Click advanced
>      Click permissions and click advance click find and add yourself
> 4. Create mounting share (in host i.e., Ubuntu)
>      sudo -s
>      nano /etc/fstab
>      add the following line
>      Change the ip address below to ip address of windows machine (guest)
>      hange the /home/%usrname% to whatever is the home dir (in 2 places)
>
>    ---

```
//%IP address of the guest machine%/Onedrive /home/%username%/onedrive cifs nofail,sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/home/%username%/.smbcreds,,users 0 0
```

---

> 5. You should see onedrive appear in the file manager on Linux
>      if not then go to terminal issue the following without sudo
>      mount ~/onedrive

Please note that you need to change the item inside % % to the specific names in your machine.

Hope this helps.

Best.